# Bootstrap submenus without dropdown

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible in bootstrap to create navbar with submenus, but not using dropdowns? I mean, the submenus sholud appear on the right of the main manu button when clicked on this button.

Comment: See this reference: http://getbootstrap.com/components/?#navbar

Comment: Or this: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html

Comment: Like I wrote, I don't want to use dropdowns

Comment: You could have a link in your top menu that toggles a collapse section - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: Can you post any attempts you've made to solve this for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Simple example using a `collapse` as a sub-menu

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                    Link that toggles submenu when clicked
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample" style="background-color: #eee">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```